# Convertir una cadena unicode a su representante en html

Tags: python, unicode

Quiero pintar un emoji en html de la sigueinte forma: 😁

```
&#128513;
```

y para ello, dispongo de su código en unicode:

`U+1F601`

¿Cómo transformo esto: **U+1F601** en esto **`&#128513;`** con python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ni siquiera necesitas conocer su código Unicode, basta con que tengas forma de insertarlo en el editor (copiándolo y pegándolo de otro sitio, por ejemplo).

```
>>> print(u''.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace'))
&#128513;
```

Ahora bien, si no tienes forma de escribirlo fácilmente pero conoces su código unicode, puedes usar el caracter de escape `\U` delante del código, si bien en ese caso necesitas especificar el código en 32 bits (8 cifras hexadecimales), que en tu caso serían `\U0001F601`. Por tanto:

```
>>> print(u'\U0001F601'.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace'))
&#128513;
```

Si lo que tienes es `"U+1F601"` en forma de cadena, puede resultar más sencillo hacer una función que haga la conversión ya que en realidad todo lo que hay que hacer es sacar el código que hay tras el `U+`, convertirlo de hexadecimal a entero, y retornar ese entero con un `&#`  delante y un punto y coma detrás.

La siguiente función haría eso:

```
def unicode_to_html(unicode_point):
  code = int(unicode_point[2:], 16)
  return "&#{};".format(code)
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
>>> unicode_to_html("U+1F601")
'&#128513;'
```